# Does Counter from collections maintain order after frequency has been considered, if all other frequencies are the same?

Tags: python, counter

Does Counter from collections maintain order after frequency has been considered?

e.g.

```
s= "leetcode"
cnt = Counter(s)
for el in s:
    if cnt[el] == 1:
        return el
```

So for the above code, the output looks something like:

```
Counter({'e': 3, 'l': 1, 't': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Now, I know Counter presents key/value in descending order, hence 'e' appears first as it has the highest count of 3, but after this all other elements have a counter of 1- does this mean that the Counter will always maintain the order of the string/array? It clearly does for the above example, but I wanted to make sure it isn't just my IDE that does this (Pycharm)

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter? Depending on your Python version a Counter may retain insertion order.

Comment: But there is no general rule of thumb? Like say in an interview could I assume this is the case? Thanks

Comment: In an interview, as in any other case, you'd have to know which version of Python was being used. Or if order matters, use a semantically ordered mapping like `OrderedDict`.

Comment: The short answer is yes!  As the docs from *Counter.most_common()* promise, "keys with equal counts are presented in the order they were encountered."  Downstream tools like *statistics.mode()* rely on this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Counter` is really just a `dict` with some extra functionality. The underlying dictionary retains insertion order in recent versions of Python, as is called out [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> *Changed in version 3.7*: As a `dict` subclass, `Counter` Inherited the capability to remember insertion order.

You can see this if you e.g. print the keys, which keep the order they were seen in the source string:

```
>>> print(cnt.keys())
dict_keys(['l', 'e', 't', 'c', 'o', 'd'])
```

However, note that the [`__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b3c50b29e14d8f089aee3e0980298bfc74cb3ba7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L722-L731) has specific handling for order:

```
def __repr__(self):
    if not self:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}()'
    try:
        # dict() preserves the ordering returned by most_common()
        d = dict(self.most_common())
    except TypeError:
        # handle case where values are not orderable
        d = dict(self)
    return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({d!r})'
```

The `Counter` is *displayed* in [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) order, whose current documentation says:

> Elements with equal counts are ordered in the order first encountered

The implementation uses [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), which is:

> ...guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to
> change the relative order of elements that compare equal...

hence retaining the insertion order of elements with equal counts.

[Earlier versions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) of the `most_common` docs, though, say:

> Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily

because the dictionary was arbitrarily ordered to begin with.